# Xamarin forms LiteDB - Real android device problem

Tags: android, xamarin.android, litedb

Using LiteDB with Xamarim forms, creating a database using this:

```
   var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
   var dirPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "MyDB.db");
```

- Debugging in an Android emulator, works fine.
- Debugging in a real device, works fine.
- Installing in a real device using .apk, does not work.

Seems the database file is not there when You tried to open it or query it .

What do I missing here?

Comment: What error or related log is produced when running this on a real device?

Comment: "message": "The type initializer for 'LiteDB.BsonExpression' threw an exception.",

"stackTrace": "  at LiteDB.LiteCollection`1[T].Query () <0x7e98d4e9b0 + 0x00048> in <b7c3b1f3825f4aed92668be2e31cab56>:0 \n  at LiteDB.LiteCollection`1[T].FindAll () <0x7e98d4ea40 + 0x00013> in <b7c3b1f3825f4aed92668be2e31cab56>:0 \n  at xxxxxx.Repository.Users.Get () [0x00006] in <3bd65f27a3f240d0b7ad01ec7b9f1ad4>:0 ",
    "innerExceptions": [
      {
        "type": "System.ArgumentNullException",
        "message": "Value cannot be null.\nParameter name: method",

Answer (score 0):

I had to whitelist LiteDB in the linker as some internals were getting removed.